# yii2 between с условием

Tags: sql, yii2

Есть запрос в Search:

> $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'date_plan', $start_date,
>   $end_date]);

Который отбирает все поля в таблице между двумя датами.
А как добавить условия, чтобы выбирались все поля между этими датами, кроме тех у которых id_importance = 1 ?
А те у которых id_importance = 1 показывались за весь период времени

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $st = ( new \yii\db\Query() )->select( "*" )
                                      ->from( 'bills' )
                                      ->andWhere( "( date_plan >= :start_date AND date_plan <= :end_date AND id_importance <> 1 ) ", [
                                          'start_date' => strtotime( $start_date ),
                                          'end_date'   => strtotime( $end_date )
                                      ] )
                                      ->orderBy( [ 'date_plan' => SORT_DESC ] );
        $query->union( $st );

        $query->andWhere(['id_importance' => 1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query->andFilterWhere("( date_plan >= :start_date AND date_plan <= :end_date ) AND id_importance <> 1", [
    'start_date' => $start_date,
    'end_date' => $end_date,
]);
$query->andFilterWhere(['id_importance' => 1]);
```

Comment: Ошибка Argument 1 passed to yii\db\Query::andFilterWhere() must be of the type array, string given, called in

Comment: тогда просто andWhere попробуйте вместо andFilterWhere

Comment: я идею понял не думаю что будет работать.
вот такое решение нашел 
`   $query->where(
    ['and',
     [
      'between',
      'date_plan',
      strtotime($start_date),
      strtotime($end_date),
     ],
     [
      'not', ['id_importance' => 1],
     ]
    ]);`
$query->andFilterWhere(['id_importance' => 1]);
но он нечего не показывает

Comment: все пусто. нечего нет

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'date_plan', $start_date, $end_date])
      ->andFilterWhere(['not', ['id_importance' => 1]])
      ->all();
```

Comment: так он выберет все записи кроме id_importance == 1 а мне 1 тоже нужна но только за весь период